# Relationship between Kronecker square and vec square

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product, vectorization

Let $X$ be a $n$ by $n$ symmetric matrix. Let vec$(X)$ denote the operator that stacks the columns of $X$ into a row vector and let $\otimes$ denote the well-known Kronecker  product.

The two $n^2$ by $n^2$ matrices vec$(X)$vec$(X)^{\top}$ and $X \otimes X$ contain the same elements but in a different order.

How are vec$(X)$vec$(X)^{\top}$ and $X \otimes X$ related algebraically?

EDIT:
[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290716/matrix-identity-involing-vec-and-kronecker-product-or-a-norm-bound?rq=1) is slightly more general and does not give an exact algebraic relation between the two.

Comment: If you take the `vec` of each matrix you'll get two vectors of length $n^4$ which are permutations of each other. Do you want someone to calculate the permutation matrix for you?  If you leave them as $n^2\times n^2$ matrices, then the permutation becomes a fourth-order tensor. Do you want those tensor components?

Comment: Ah, that’s a good idea. I’ll try to come up with the permutation matrix for the vec transformation of each matrix myself. Thanks! So fourth-order tensor means that it cannot be represented as a $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix?

Comment: I suggest that you load $X$ with prime numbers. That way the elementx of each $n^2\times n^2$ matrix will have a unique factorization and will help you match them up.  You might be able to split the tensor into two $n^2\times n^2$ permutations on either side of the $X$-derived matrices.

Comment: Ok, thanks will try it as soon as I get the time.